# Sequelize having two types of associations between two tables. (1:1 and 1:m)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models

1. documents
2. documentVersions

These two models have two different types of associations:

1. A document has many document versions:

```
  Document.hasMany(models.DocumentVersion, {
      foreignKey: { name: 'documentId', allowNull: false },
      sourceKey: 'id',
      onDelete: 'cascade',
      as: 'documentVersion'
    });
 
 DocumentVersion.belongsTo(models.Document, {
            foreignKey: { name: 'documentId', allowNull: false },
            targetKey: 'id',
            onDelete: 'cascade',
            as: 'document'
        });
```

This works fine creating a documentId foreign key in document version model.

2. Every document has one active documentVersion. So document model should have one active documentVersion Id.

I tried added the following along with above associations:

```
 Document.hasOne(models.DocumentVersion, {
      foreignKey: { name: 'activeVersionId', allowNull: false },
      targetKey: 'id',
      as: 'activeDocumentVersion'
    });
```

But this ended up adding activeVersionId in the documentVersion table instead of document table.

How can I add the second association?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have cyclic dependency when you create associations with constraints set to false. Please read [this docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/constraints-and-circularities.html)

```
    Document.belongsTo(models.DocumentVersion, {
      foreignKey: { name: 'activeVersionId', allowNull: false },
      targetKey: 'id',
      constraints: false,
      as: 'activeDocumentVersion'
    });
```